# Curl Element Not Found Error

Tags: php, curl

I am stuck in a situation when I get content of a web page through CURL then I received page content but got error query result not present there. I always got element not found error.

But when I put URL in browser then got appropriate result. How can I resolve that?

URL I am using is `http://164.100.9.38/judis/handle/123456789/30346/simple-search?query=%28%28petitioner:ajay%29%29&from_advanced=true&query11=&query9=&query8=&conjunction8=AND&conjunction9=AND&query10=&conjunction6=AND&conjunction7=AND&field5=judge&field4=petitioner&field3=respondent&field2=caseyear&field9=abstract&field8=type&field7=datejudgement&conjunction10=AND&field6=headnotes&query4=ajay&query5=&query6=&query7=&field1=casenumber&query1=&query2=&query3=&conjunction3=AND&conjunction2=AND&conjunction5=AND&conjunction4=AND&field10=citation&conjunction1=AND&field11=keyword&num_search_field=11`

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the cURL script ?

Comment: Does it work with a simple URL (just google) ?

Comment: how to you access it browser?

Comment: I get `Error: Document Not Found` in browser. Are you logged in there?

Comment: Just Try It.    http://164.100.9.38/judis/handle/123456789/30346/simple-search?query=%28%28petitioner:ajay%29%29&from_advanced=true&query11=&query9=&query8=&conjunction8=AND&conjunction9=AND&query10=&conjunction6=AND&conjunction7=AND&field5=judge&field4=petitioner&field3=respondent&field2=caseyear&field9=abstract&field8=type&field7=datejudgement&conjunction10=AND&field6=headnotes&query4=ajay&query5=&query6=&query7=&field1=casenumber&query1=&query2=&query3=&conjunction3=AND&conjunction2=AND&conjunction5=AND&conjunction4=AND&field10=citation&conjunction1=AND&field11=keyword&num_search_field=11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to login on the site first or create a session first. They are using session. Surprisingly they are providing session id on page `http://164.100.9.38/judis/styles.css.jsp`.

So **request `http://164.100.9.38/judis/styles.css.jsp` first**. It'll set the cookie. And then request your usual way.

To keep your session cookies use `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

Comment: They are using session. You might have to login first or enable cookies in curl

Comment: Can you please check that how we can get cookies from site or set for the same???

Comment: If you want to manipulate single cookies, you'll need to parse the `Set-cookie` header

Comment: Did you read my answer? I have clearly stated that you need to send a request to a specific url (see answer) which will set the cookie.